# Cannot choose HDD at installation

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

I have a question. 
I'm trying to install this OS on my HDD instead if my SSD, but the problem is that my HDD seems like not to show up on the list, always shows up as "unknown" but I've already made some partition in windows (NTFS): [Picture of the menu](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7IGGy9DK81Nwa9PFknb_jsKnJ8zfxnvvU2TCE9f_pf0ATpLLCB_5G2TFi9g0ZjmbKYpOQRMWiDC0tM0t7c1dE3qIGgIGff-Heqs4y1uVuURmoSJnT9Jw9U7oJpIGaI4wEQiQBedQC77elJW1Q01mNF-4pXv2igWqcjMVzX7EGA87S28aL-MTheVt1dkaqgKiW8-F92ZWo7rimIXRLRCGMwf6LGJbtRv1JSzM823rLwSzK2-7LrdkGqJp8l30j6YsyU0yYpmzl4hLtjVh1AO3CcyA4tqMx3ITeSnA03XQpbefMpYPoAekgg7TToqlCUvDhQiK30Oalvt43ZJ-cKiYf1-f-xvKGvsoXQ6aifzMbyQyuYSP_cNx44G6f68an9VNNZmV16oet6z_NbB4e5da2ZXINVspwndi7E1vXAFB8cYeG99HGd_HqjR7igUMhjWELd3tb7EjVBR2BSOhHebbIZ4BcIttL6vBbuarAbte4-SG-80gmJkYVf2KGdI448qnKjXAecH1OxcNh4DXHJQJSoWTdtCkbqe6uu_e3T8E2fYvTmGkG8C8ljOgJPrOTeteWAHC=w1567-h881-no)

Can anyone tell me what I have to do? I tried both using a USB Stick and DVD, neither of them worked for me...

Thanks in advance!

-d3v_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be 2 problems:

1. You can't install elementary OS on NTFS.
   (and even if you can, you shouldn't do that)
   Solution: Delete the NTFS Partition and create a new ext4 partition with the installation manager.
2. You have to shut down Windows completly. Since Windows 8 its blocking the NTFS Partition, so it fast boot will work.
   Solution: Open the command prompt and execute:

   ```
   shutdown.exe /s /t 0 /f
   ```

   and restart the installation